# Execute animation on main_queue in Objective C, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm working on a code that was made by other guy in my company that left and there is something that I don't understand why he did this: I'm setting my keyboard listeners on the function `[self setKeyboardListenersInRegisterView]`

The code:

```
- (void)setKeyboardListenersInRegisterView {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onKeyboardHideInRegisterView:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onKeyboardShowInRegisterView:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

But, he is calling this function here:

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //listener for keyboard show/hide
        [self setKeyboardListenersInRegisterView];
        [self.studentUsernameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.studentUsernameTextField addTarget:self.studentPasswordTextField action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    });
```

So, you guys know why is he calling the function inside of the main_queue and not outside of it? Important to say that the selectors of my keyboard's notification are executing an animation (just setting the view some pixels up in order to see what is the user writing).

Comment: Well, obviously he wants the animation to be delayed 1 second. Every UI update must be done on the main thread. The wait time itself is a bit suspicious though.

Comment: As @Sulthan said, all UI actions should always handle in Main thread

Comment: If you run this code without main thread, there is no guarantee that this code will execute. This also suggests that this is being called from a background thread. So the key is - for doing UI operation from  background thread, always use main thread.

Comment: What about adding observers? Do they need to be added on main thread?

Comment: The observers should be added when the view is loaded but is appearing. And removed when the view is disappearing. Which is why should be added and removed in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear.

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter` is thread-safe, but if you were to add these observations on a background thread, the observation might be added after the event being observed has already occurred. I don't see anything surprising in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to speak to an interface object in any way, shape, or form otherwise than on the main thread, you are doing wrong. In Xcode 9, you'll actually get dinged for doing this (assuming you have the Main Thread Checker turned on in your scheme, which you definitely should).